# How can I make a setup.exe for xdelta files?

Tags: installation

I wanna build a language patch which involves Xdelta. Right now I am able patch the original files via batch file but it requires Xdelta files and batch file to be fixed in the target directory.

What I am saying is: a setup that has functions of Xdelta would be convenient 'cause I wanna make it user-friendly and I don't want anyone else to see command lines written down as they install the patch. How can I build such a thing?

Comment: Welcome! I've made some minor edits to your question including adding the [tag:installer] tag, but I'm worried that the question will end up being closed because it's really broad. In order for someone to answer it well, they would basically need to create the tool you want. I think you're more likely to receive help if you can do a bit more research and perhaps come up with an attempt, even if you can't quite get it to work. Cheers!

Comment: I've searched everywhere and no results :(